# How to make a project inside a submodule?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have recently found the neat submodules feature of git and I would like to use it. But as I have seen, a submodule goes inside a project... like this:

```
Project
   Submodule
```

but if I would like to develop a library or plugin, how do I work around? I would have a software and inside it I would develop my project ending with this structure:

```
Submodule
   Project
```

That way the software can get upgraded and I can upgrade the plugin on a new version.

I have read some tutorials and information but I'm not sure how to make the second approach.

Comment: What would be wrong with using a submodule for the plugin?  This would allow you to separate this dependency from your main Git project.  Towards this end, you sort of answered your own question.

Comment: My project is the plugin. I do not develop the main project on which the plugin will go inside but I need the main project to keep up to date. And as I'm new to submodule I'm yet not sure of the correct approach.

Comment: Have a look here: https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-submodules-34c65e940407 ... To thoroughly cover your question really requires an entire blog on submodules.

Comment: I don't understand your question. A submodule, by definition, resides inside another repository. A top-level library repository is just a regular repository, not a submodule.